# Problems with the custom validator in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, customvalidator

I know that the question in question has already been asked in many other posts but in all the proposed solutions I cannot find one that solves the problem for me.

I'm trying to create a validator to check that the entered confirmation password is the same as the password.

This is my build form code:

```
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      surname : new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      tempUsername: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(16)]),
      passwordTemp: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    }, { validator: this.matchingPasswords }
    );
  }
```

and this is my validator method:

```
  public matchingPasswords(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const password = c.get(['passwords']);
    const confirmPassword = c.get(['passwordTemp']);

    if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
      return { mismatchedPasswords: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

in line 8 of the build form I get the following error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ validator: (c: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'validator' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `validators` not `validator`:

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({
 // fields
}, { validators: this.matchingPasswords });
```

Perhaps it's also better to move that `matchingPasswords` to an exported utility function, but that's just personal code preference.

Other working notations are:

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({
 // fields
}, this.matchingPasswords);
```

```js
this.form = new FormGroup({
 // fields
}, [this.matchingPasswords]);
```

Comment: thank you very much @PoulKruijt, putting validators instead of validator the error vanishes. Now when opening the signup modal there are a lot of errors that I will try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Use validators instead of validator

```
{ validators: this.matchingPasswords }
```

and this

```
public matchingPasswords: ValidatorFn = (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        const password = c.get('passwords');
        const confirmPassword = c.get('passwordTemp');

        if (password && confirmPassword && password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
            return { mismatchedPasswords: true };
        }

        return null;
    };
```